# Deterministic processing on probabilistic input

Tags: algorithms, terminology

I've designed an algorithm, is which responsible to process some samples from normal distribution under aegis of some deterministic steps. In other words, the algorithm generate unique response to a unique set of the random set of input.

Now I am prone to plan a title for the corresponding paper and there is a noticeable ambiguity regarding the manner by which the algorithm could be addressed...

It is neither non-deterministic nor randomized and probabilistic. What is this algorithm type? Should I name that as typical deterministic?!...

Edit: This algorithm is supposed to be fed by a number of agent coordinates (are which random normal-driven integer numbers). It should colonize the agents into groups in a specialized manner. Thus, the input is probabilistic but both the algorithm process and the output are considerably deterministic.

The current idea regarding the title is:

`Optimal Communication of Agents by the Probabilistic Colonization of the Robot Swarm`

But that `Probabilistic` word does not sound so deserving...

Comment: I think there is too little information to answer this. What is the full proposed title? How is the type relevant? In which context does the algorithm exist?

Comment: @Raphael: Please check the applied edit...

Comment: What about : `Optimal Communication of randomly placed Agents by the Colonization of the Robot Swarm`.  I am not sure what some of these wrods are supposed to mean. But you said that the random part is the coordinates of agents.

Comment: @babou: Yes... You got the case... The suggestion is comprehensive and reasonable, however `randomly placed` does not sound reverberating, literally. That is your kindness if you let me know if you will brainstorm something else...

Comment: How about `Optimal Communication of Agents under Randomized Spatial Distribution`?

Comment: @collapsar: It is considerably excellent... prestigious and deserving to be considered as the title for a paper journal... Thank you... Please send the suggestion as the answer, and I can confirm that...

Comment: Is this really a good question? Seems highly opinion-based to me.

Comment: @Juho: Technically, the suitable title should be verbally high-level and also illustrate the overall phantom of the work... The presented offer might be evaluated commensurate, however one could assert that any edit would be possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about ...

```
Optimal Communication of Agents under Randomized Spatial Distribution
```